# Pgrouting in postgres - cannot create extension

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, postgis, pgrouting

I installed postgres with EDB installer. I wanted to use pgrouting in my database. So I downloaded it through homebrew `brew install pgrouting`

Next, I wanted to initalize it in my database: `psql mydatabase -c "create extension pgrouting;"`

But I got this error `ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/postgresql/extension/pgrouting.control": No such file or directory`

I found `pgrouting.control` in `/usr/local/Cellar/pgrouting/2.4.1/share/postgresql/extension/pgrouting.control`

Should I just copy those files from /usr... to /Library/Postgres... ??

Comment: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/795 << I described (sort of) in very unprofessional way how to get around it

Answer (score 1):

Yup that sounds like a reasonable solution.

Comment: I did, then it demanded lib file :) I did solve it by VERY UNPROFESSIONAL. I described it here: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/795

Answer (score 1):

Personally, doing the following worked for me just fine:

- install **pgrouting** via homebrew
- find all the `.sql` scripts related to **pgrouting** in the following location: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgrouting/HEAD-441037f/share/postgresql@14/extension`

  - copy and paste all those into the path where the *postgres* contents area located -> `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/share/postgresql/extension`
- lastly, copy the following `.so` file `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pgrouting/HEAD-441037f/lib/postgresql@14/libpgrouting-3.4.so` into the respective location within the Postgres contents -> `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/lib/postgresql`